# Trigger checkbox click with button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to change my 'send' button which onClick sends a message from an input box to a div, to also trigger the click of a 'checkbox' input.

**HTML**

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Post</button> 
   <input name="stry" type="text" id="stry"/> 
   <input name="nope" type="text" id="message-input"/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="sendsms" onclick="copyStory(this)">
```

*These buttons are actually in a form

**JS**

```
 function copyStory(ch) {
     if (ch.checked)
         var text1 = document.getElementById("message-input").value;
     else
         text1 = '';
     document.getElementById("stry").value = text1;
 }
```

I've searched around but I can't find a way to make the send button trigger the checkbox, any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using jQuery? And where is _send_ button?

Comment: `jQuery('[name="sendsms"]').click()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you need is to have same handler for both `onclick` and `onchange` events. Try this way,

***HTML :***

```
<input type="button" id="sendButton" value="Send" onclick="copyStory(this)" />
<input name="nope" type="text" id="message-input"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="sendsms" onchange="copyStory(this)"/>

<div id="msgDiv"></div>
```

***javaScript :***

```
 function copyStory(ch) {
     var text1
     if (ch.checked || ch.id == "sendButton")
         text1 = document.getElementById("message-input").value;
     else
         text1 = document.getElementById("msgDiv").innerText = "";

     document.getElementById("msgDiv").innerText = text1;
 }
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/c6fp83Lw/)

Comment: I don't see why you changed document.getEelemntById..... code? It seemed fine to just change the 'if' part

Comment: op mentioned to send the `message from an input box to a div`. But didn't find any `div` to show the message. So created a div and also removed the unnecessary codes irrelevant to this problem.